# Using OleDbConnection how to randomize words

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

Using an OleDbConnection how would you connect to a table in Access which contains 20 words and then get it to randomly pick a word from the table and store it in the label on the form?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    // Use this connection string if your database has the extension .accdb
    private const String access7ConnectionString =
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\WordsDB.accdb";


    // Data components
    private OleDbConnection myConnection;
    private DataTable myDataTable;
    private OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter;
    private OleDbCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder;

    // Index of the current record
    private int currentRecord = 0;


    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String command = "SELECT * FROM Words";
        try
        {
            myConnection = new OleDbConnection(access7ConnectionString);
            myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(access7ConnectionString, myConnection);
            myCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(myAdapter);
            myDataTable = new DataTable();
            FillDataTable(command);
            DisplayRow(currentRecord);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void FillDataTable(String selectCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = selectCommand;
            // Fill the datatable with the rows reurned by the select command
            myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in FillDataTable : \r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void DisplayRow(int rowIndex)
    {
        // Check that we can retrieve the given row
        if (myDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
            return; // nothing to display
        if (rowIndex >= myDataTable.Rows.Count)
            return; // the index is out of range

        // If we get this far then we can retrieve the data
        try
        {
            DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows[rowIndex];
            WordsLbl.Text = row["SpellingWords"].ToString();   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in DisplayRow : \r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this is the code, what i am trying to understand is, how do you get a random word from the table in the database and store it in the label? Also, I am using OleDbConnection in order to connect to the database!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It's easier to help when you have already made a start.

Comment: @gunr2171 there you go, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsEnumerable` on your `DataTable`, then you can select a random word inside of it.For example after you fill your datatable:

```
FillDataTable(command); 
var words = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(d => d["word"].ToString())
     .ToList();

Random rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, words.Count + 1);

string randomWord = words[randomNumber];
label1.Text = randomWord;
```

This should work.Just you should change `word` with your column name in your database in this line:    `.Select(d => d["word"].ToString())`

Comment: Thanks for you answer it has no errors however the random word is not displayed in the label

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing 'Rejected Edits' to my Answer, here is the part that applies to the original question asked:

You can try using the "Random" Class to generate a random number like this:

```
// =========== Get a Random Number first, then call DisplayRow() ===============

// Figure out the upper range of numbers to choose from the rows returned
int maxCount = myDataTable.Rows.Count;

// generate a random number to use for "rowIndex" in your 'myDataTable.Rows[rowIndex]'
Random randomNR = new Random();
int myRndNR = randomNR.Next(0, maxCount - 1);

// Execute your DisplayRow(int rowIndex) using myRndNR
DisplayRow(myRndNR);

// ===========
```

As for why your program was not working (asked in the comments), I recommended the following:

I copied and pasted your code into a new Project plus created an Access Database as you described... I believe the problems you are having are:

Problem One: Your program is not finding "WordsDB.accdb".

Possible Solutions:

(1) You can either figure out how to create the correct |DataDirectory| path in your "Connection String" or

(2) put your "WordsDB.accdb" in a folder you can reference with a full path like this "Data Source=**C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app_data\WordsDB.accdb**" so your "Connection String" looks like this:

```
private const String access7ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app_data\WordsDB.accdb";
```

Problem Two: You need to move the Random code out of the current location so that it is executed after the DataTable is filled.

Possible Solution:

(1) Change your Form1.cs to look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Use this connection string if your database has the extension .accdb
        private const String access7ConnectionString =
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app_data\WordsDB.accdb";


        // Data components
        private OleDbConnection myConnection;
        private DataTable myDataTable;
        private OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter;
        private OleDbCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder;

        // Index of the current record
        private int currentRecord = 0;

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String command = "SELECT * FROM Words";
            try
            {
                myConnection = new OleDbConnection(access7ConnectionString);
                myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(access7ConnectionString, myConnection);
                myCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(myAdapter);
                myDataTable = new DataTable();
                FillDataTable(command);
                /* Move this "DisplayRow(currentRecord);" down below and use 
                   after you get a random number to pick a random word as shown
                   below... */
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

// =========== Get a Random Number first, then call DisplayRow() ===============

            // Figure out the upper range of numbers to choose from the rows returned
            int maxCount = myDataTable.Rows.Count;

            // generate a random number to use for "rowIndex" in your 'myDataTable.Rows[rowIndex]'
            Random randomNR = new Random();
            int myRndNR = randomNR.Next(0, maxCount - 1);

            // Execute your DisplayRow(int rowIndex) using myRndNR
            DisplayRow(myRndNR);

// ===========

        }

        private void FillDataTable(String selectCommand)
        {
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = selectCommand;
                // Fill the DataTable with the rows returned by the select command
                myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in FillDataTable : \r\n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void DisplayRow(int rowIndex)
        {
            // Check that we can retrieve the given row
            if (myDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
                return; // nothing to display
            if (rowIndex >= myDataTable.Rows.Count)
                return; // the index is out of range

            // If we get this far then we can retrieve the data
            try
            {
                DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows[rowIndex];
                WordsLbl.Text = row["SpellingWords"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in DisplayRow : \r\n" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Potential Problem:

You may not have the 'Event, Behavior, Load' for your Form set to execute

```
MainForm_Load
```

Potential Solution:

a. Go to the Design View in Visual Studio and right click on your Form.

b. Click on "Properties" on the pop up window

c. In the "Properties" window (may be down in the lower right corner of Visual Studio) look for "Events"

d. Once you find "Events", look for "Behavior" (if you are sorting your Properties  by 'Categories') or "Load" (if you have Properties sorted alphabetically)

e. In the "Load" box, make sure it says "MainForm_Load"

Comment: The table is being filled when the Form loads and you are not getting any errors, right? Once the form has loaded and is running, is the last "SpellingWords" word in the actual database appearing on the form as your "WordsLbl"?

Comment: Nope nothing at all.. no words

Comment: Its working, can you explain everything what you did there please?

Comment: Since it is working, I am assuming you figured out how to create a valid connection string to your database (WordsDB.accdb) and verified that the "MainForm_Load" was being called when you ran the program... The only real change I made was moving the method "DisplayRow(currentRecord);" to run **after** your DataSet and DataTable were filled. Please see the comments in my example above about "DisplayRow".

Comment: Okay I understhand, thanks for the answer btw I really appreciate it.. also say if i was to have a "go" button, how would you get it to change to another random word and store it in the label?

Comment: Cool :) For the button, I would use the the Button's OnClick Event to execute/run the same actions shown above between the // ==== comments where I figure out how many rows/words I have to choose from and then use that to pick one at "Random" to pass to your "DisplayRow()" function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using access, this is what you can do once you've got your datatable populated with rows. I have been able to test this after populating the datatable. I populated my datatable from a different database, but that doesn't matter. The last 4 lines of my code help you get a random record from the datatable each time.

```
{
    const string query = "SELECT name FROM NewTable";
    var command = new SqlCommand(){CommandText = query, CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,Connection=sqlConn};
    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter() { SelectCommand = command };
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Names");
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

    int count = dataTable.Rows.Count; 
    int index = new Random().Next(count);

    DataRow d = dataTable.Rows[index];
    Console.WriteLine(d[0]);

}
```